# Sql Apache Spark connector from data bricks to sqlserver for Bulk insertion : performance issue

Tags: sql-server, scala, apache-spark, bulkinsert, azure-databricks

This is my problem statment and  requirement, looking for some help

“ We are using the spark connector to import the data from the delta files into azure sqlserver, our entities are close to 60 million records this connector has helped us to import the data from my notebook successful. As our entities were growing the need to import the data into sqlserver has also increased the load, we have observed some performance issues arising with this increase in load. I have observed that the Bulk operation is creating multiple connections to the  sqlsever and I can see there are range of 70 connections created for the same  operation ( insert bulk in my case ) but only one is running as I have the tablock and other are in waiting state but my CPU consumption spikes to 100% and other jobs get failed because of this.

My questions : Can we control the connections or concurrency being raised /operated from the spark connector, can you help me with this state of problem on how we can control the connections & consumption of CPU

Comment: what connector do you use? plus connector configuration

Comment: How are you actually loading the data? `BULK INSERT` with native format data is much faster than character data, and faster again if you're in a scenario where `TABLOCK` can be used. If you're talking about multiple connections, though, it sounds like you're using some other solution.